# How should one invoke docker to take care of the PID 1 problem with zombie processes?

Tags: docker, init, zombie-process

The `phusion/baseimage` boasts of taking care of the pid 1 problem with a light weight init process. How can one use the phusion/baseimage properly? I tried to invoke the image with the command `ps aux` shows `ps` running with a PID 1.

What did I do wrong? What is the proper way to use the image?

```
me@host:~/app1$ docker run --rm phusion/baseimage ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  3.0  0.0  29180  1404 ?        Rs   01:27   0:00 ps aux
```

Answer (score 2):

docker has an option `--init`. That starts init system [tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini) as Pid 1.

`tini` is stored as `/usr/bin/docker-init` on host.
Unfortunately, some systems like fedora and openSUSE miss the init binary although `--init` shows up in `docker run --help`.

You can add `tini` to your docker images yourself and define entrypoint with
`ENTRYPOINT /tini --`. See [README for tini](https://github.com/krallin/tini).

Further informations about missing `/usr/bin/docker-init` at: https://github.com/mviereck/x11docker/issues/23#issuecomment-386817295

Answer (score 0):

I figured out ([from here](https://github.com/phusion/baseimage-docker#whats_inside)) that the proper way to use the `phusion/baseimage` is to run it as -

```
docker run --rm -t -i phusion/baseimage /sbin/my_init ps aux`
```

to have `my_init` execute as PID1 and have `my_init` spawn a process for `ps aux`

```
*** Running /etc/my_init.d/00_regen_ssh_host_keys.sh...
*** Running /etc/my_init.d/10_syslog-ng.init...
May  8 04:18:23 daf3cfab8573 syslog-ng[10]: syslog-ng starting up; version='3.5.6'
May  8 04:18:23 daf3cfab8573 syslog-ng[10]: WARNING: you are using the pipe driver, underlying file is not a FIFO, it should be used by file(); filename='/dev/stdout'
May  8 04:18:24 daf3cfab8573 syslog-ng[10]: EOF on control channel, closing connection;
*** Running /etc/rc.local...
*** Booting runit daemon...
*** Runit started as PID 16
*** Running ps aux...
May  8 04:18:24 daf3cfab8573 cron[20]: (CRON) INFO (pidfile fd = 3)
May  8 04:18:24 daf3cfab8573 cron[20]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  5.0  0.0  32304 10796 ?        Ss+  04:18   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 -u /sbin/my_init ps aux
root        10  1.0  0.0  72364  7552 ?        S    04:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/syslog-ng --pidfile /var/run/syslog-ng.pid -F --no-caps
root        16  0.0  0.0   4392  1124 ?        S+   04:18   0:00 /usr/bin/runsvdir -P /etc/service
root        17  0.0  0.0  37656  3340 ?        R+   04:18   0:00 ps aux
root        18  0.0  0.0   4240   672 ?        Ss   04:18   0:00 runsv cron
root        19  0.0  0.0   4240   800 ?        Ss   04:18   0:00 runsv sshd
root        20  0.0  0.0  29272  2840 ?        S    04:18   0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
*** ps exited with status 0.
*** Shutting down runit daemon (PID 16)...
*** Running /etc/my_init.post_shutdown.d/10_syslog-ng.shutdown...
May  8 04:18:24 daf3cfab8573 syslog-ng[10]: syslog-ng shutting down; version='3.5.6'
May  8 04:18:24 daf3cfab8573 syslog-ng[10]: EOF on control channel, closing connection;
*** Killing all processes...
```